# Change text color of a span with Javascript while hovering on seperated div

Tags: javascript, colors, highlight, megamenu

I have a menupoint and underneath it a seperate div / mega menu. I triggered the mega menu to show up via Javascript. When I am hovering over the mega menu, the desired span in the menu should get highlighted with another color and also the background color should change. You can see in the code how I tried to solve it (comments included). Can you please help me. I don´t know why I can´t trigger it via .getElementsByClassName!?

```js
//Showing mega menu on hover over menu point

document.getElementById("menu-item-136").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
document.getElementById("menu-item-136").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("mega-menu").style.display = "block";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("mega-menu").style.display = "none";
}



//Let mega menu stay visible when hovering over it
//Style menupoint when hovering over mega menu div (NOT WORKING)!

document.getElementById("mega-menu").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
document.getElementById("mega-menu").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("mega-menu").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName (".aux-menu-label").style.color = "yellow";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("mega-menu").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName (".aux-menu-label").style.color = "";
}
```

```css
.menu-item-136 {
background-color: grey;
height: 50px;
}

.menu-item-136:hover {
background-color:green;
}

.aux-menu-label {
color:blue;
}

.mega-menu-1 {
display: none;
background-color: green;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<li id="menu-item-136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-136 aux-menu-depth-0 aux-menu-root-2 aux-menu-item">
            <a href="#" class="aux-item-content">
                <span class="aux-menu-label"><i aria-hidden="true" class="services auxicon-list"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Leistungen</span>
            <span class="aux-submenu-indicator"></span></a>
</div>



<div id="mega-menu" class="mega-menu-1">content</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your example is using getElementsByClassName which refers to more than one element with the same class. However, your HTML shows only one element with class `aux-menu-label`. Will you have more of these in your project? - Additionally, you have an `li` that is just floating around without a parent `ul` or `ol`. You should clean this up a bit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Well, does this only work when I enter more than one class? I tried a lot with mouseover and "ElementsByClass" but nothing worked. I want that this applies only to this one menu point (Leistungen). But there are more "aux-menu-label" elements in the menu... they have a unique li id though for their parent. In my head this seems so easy. "Change color of this span when hovered over that div". Mmmmh

Comment: See my answer below, there are other issues with your code but I've simply provided an answer to your problem with `getElementsByClassName` and added additional labels to your HTML for the code to work properly. It would have helped if you included more of your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit messy but you are calling your class incorrectly:

This:

```
document.getElementsByClassName (".aux-menu-label")
```

Should be this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName ("aux-menu-label")
```

Additionally, when using `getElementsByClassName` you are provided with an array-like object with all elements that have the class you have specified.

With that in mind, you must run a loop to target elements with the styles you want to apply.

The below code is how we will target multiple labels and change them to yellow on hover:

```
  var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("aux-menu-label");
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].style.color = "yellow"
  }
```

When you run the snippet below you will see I have used similar code to revert the color back to blue `onmouseout`.

Learn more about `getElementsByClassName` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

```js
//Including this to show you how to target CSS child elements as described in your comment
var childElement = document.querySelector('#menu-item-136 .aux-item-content'); 
childElement.style.backgroundColor = "white";
console.log(childElement);

//Showing mega menu on hover over menu point

document.getElementById("menu-item-136").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
document.getElementById("menu-item-136").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("mega-menu").style.display = "block";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("mega-menu").style.display = "none";
}



//Let mega menu stay visible when hovering over it
//Style menupoint when hovering over mega menu div (NOT WORKING)!

document.getElementById("mega-menu").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
document.getElementById("mega-menu").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("mega-menu").style.display = "block";
  var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("aux-menu-label");
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[0].style.color = "yellow"
  }
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("mega-menu").style.display = "none";
  var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("aux-menu-label");
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].style.color = "blue"
  }
}
```

```css
.menu-item-136 {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50px;
}

.menu-item-136:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.aux-menu-label {
  color: blue;
}

.mega-menu-1 {
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <li id="menu-item-136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-136 aux-menu-depth-0 aux-menu-root-2 aux-menu-item">
    <a href="#" class="aux-item-content">
      <span class="aux-menu-label"><i aria-hidden="true" class="services auxicon-list"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Leistungen</span>
      <span class="aux-submenu-indicator"></span></a>
</div>



<div id="mega-menu" class="mega-menu-1">content</div>

<div>
  <li id="menu-item-136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-136 aux-menu-depth-0 aux-menu-root-2 aux-menu-item">
    <a href="#" class="aux-item-content">
      <span class="aux-menu-label"><i aria-hidden="true" class="services auxicon-list"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Leistungen</span>
      <span class="aux-submenu-indicator"></span></a>
</div>



<div id="mega-menu" class="mega-menu-1">content</div>
```

EDIT: I've included the following javascript to show you how to target child elements and apply CSS to them. The code below will target the child of `#menu-item-136` and change its background color to white. Run the snippet to see.

```
var childElement = document.querySelector('#menu-item-136 .aux-item-content'); 
childElement.style.backgroundColor = "white";
console.log(childElement);
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Thats surely getting me closer. Really cool. The only issue now is, that all labels turn to yellow. Can I avoid that somehow? It would be nice just to add the color to the label "Leistungen". Is it possible to specify the selection like in CSS with `#menu-item-123 > .aux-item-content` ? That would be awesome!

Comment: If you want to target a specific label for instance the first label you can do `labels[0].style.color = "yellow"` since the output of getElementsByClassName is an array you can target specific elements by their index. Indexes start and 0 so `labels[0].style.color = "yellow"` will target the first link, labels[1].style.color = "yellow" will target the second link and so on... Run the updated snippet.

Comment: To answer your question, you can target child elements with javascript like this: `var childElement = document.querySelector('#menu-item-136 .aux-item-content');
  console.log(childElement);`  Give it a try.

Comment: Also updated my answer to show you an example of the above code.

Comment: Man you killed it! Thank u so much. Starting with Javascript reminds me of my first steps when I started with HTML or CSS. I thought I would die. But with people like u thinks get more clear. Still I have to learn a lot. Thank u! :)

Comment: ...That´s a good idea. For now I just added the correct index number and that works perfect! But it´s good to know how I can target the child that way! Thank u!

Comment: Just like you, I still have much to learn myself which is why I love coding. There is never a dull day. - I'm happy we got to the bottom of it your issue and happy to help! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**In your code
If we add some margin to megamenu wrapper This will be not working
and menu close when pointer out from menu item.**

*I have fixed that isseue*

Its Looks like with WordPress menu. Please check below example and its will be helpful to use multiple mega-menues You need to map megamenu data id with menu class item.

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/danushka181/pen/BaLBzKz)

```js
 [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li'), function (link) {
        link.addEventListener('mouseover', coloringHandler);
        link.addEventListener('mouseout', decoloringHandler);
    });

    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.megamenu'), function (menu) {
        menu.addEventListener('mouseover', megamenuHover );
    });


    var state = false;
    
    function coloringHandler(){
        state = false;
        hideAllMegamenu();
        // add class to current hover element
        this.classList.add('active');
        var Classes = this.classList; // getting all class list
        Classes.forEach(name => {
            var megaMenu  = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="'+name+'"]'); // check if have any mached elements with class name 
            if(megaMenu.length == 1 ){
                megaMenu[0].classList.add('active');
                state = true;

                megaMenu[0].addEventListener('mouseover', megamenuHover );
                megaMenu[0].addEventListener('mouseout', megamenuHoverOut );

                return;
            }
        });
    }

    function decoloringHandler(){
        if( state == false ){
            this.classList.remove('active');
            hideAllMegamenu();
        }
    }

    function hideAllMegamenu(){
        // change elemets as you want
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li'), function (li) {
            li.classList.remove("active");
        });
        // .megamenu is common class
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.megamenu'), function (menues) {
            menues.classList.remove('active');
        })
    }

    function  megamenuHover() {
        this.classList.add('in-hover');
    }

    function megamenuHoverOut() {
        hideAllMegamenu();
    }
```

```css
nav ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style:none;
    }

    li{
    margin:0px 10px;
    }

    a{
    background:green;
    display:block;
    color:white;
    padding:10px 20px;
    }

    ul li.active a{
    background:red;
    }


    .megamenu{
    background: red;
    height:200px;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity:0;
      position:absolute;
            width:100%;
      padding:20px;
      color:#fff;
      transition:all .5s ease;
      transform:translateY(50px);
    }

    .megamenu.active{
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: all;
      transform:translateY(0px);
    }
```

```html
<h1>Hover over the menu Items</h1> 
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li class="menu-item-136">
       <a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
     </li>
     <li class="menu-item-137">
       <a href="#"><span>Contact us</span></a>
     </li>
     <li class="menu-item-138">
       <a href="#"><span>Danushka</span></a>
     </li>
     
     <li class="menu-item-139">
       <a href="#"><span>About us</span></a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</nav>

<div class="megamenu" data-id="menu-item-137">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
</div>
<div class="megamenu" data-id="menu-item-138">
  Danushka Megamenu... Add data id for mapping
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, you killed it completely with building a whole mega menu with Javascript! :D Thanks that´s very nice of you! ;) This will be helpful for future projects. But perhaps you can help me to just specify the class name (see my comment under "Aib Codes Daily" reply). It works now but I need to target just that specific class under the id "menu-item-136". Can I achive that? Thanks for your work here! :)

Comment: Yes you can, use megame data id as you want and it will be appear when hover menu item with class "menu-item-136" :)
`<div class="megamenu" data-id="menu-item-136">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
</div>`

You can add field to wordpress backend and use it as megamenu data-id

Comment: Your current solution will not work if add some margin to megamenu element. if your are using it please dont add any margin top values to megame menu div :p

Comment: As I want the mega menu directly under the "link" of the navigation point, it is ok the way I did it. So there will be no margin where the div would disappear when I would hover over the margin. Thanks for your infos! ;)